# Programatically Remove Item from Cart Not Working - Needs Page Refresh

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax

I am trying to add a free product to the cart if the order total is above $199.99

I have achieved this and it is working. The issue is that I need to remove the product if the user then deletes an item from the cart and goes below $199.99 again (to prevent  gaming the system).

What I have seems to be working. The problem is that it seems I need to click 2 links before the REMOVE FROM CART action seems to be working (or refresh the page).

What is causing this? Can the remove action be accomplished with AJAX by any chance?

```
// -------------------------------------------
// ADD PRODUCT IF ORDER MINIMUM ABOVE 200

/*
* Automatically adding the product to the cart when cart total amount reach to $199.99.
*/

function aapc_add_product_to_cart() {
    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_total = 199.99;   

    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total >= $cart_total ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $free_product_id = 339;  // Product Id of the free product which will get added to cart
            $found      = false;

            //check if product already in cart
            if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                    $_product = $values['data'];
                    if ( $_product->get_id() == $free_product_id )
                        $found = true;                  
                }
                // if product not found, add it
                if ( ! $found )
                    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            } else {
                // if no products in cart, add it
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product_id );
            }        
        }
    }
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total <= $cart_total && $found ) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $free_product_id );
            }       
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'aapc_add_product_to_cart' );

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_product_from_cart_programmatically' );

function remove_product_from_cart_programmatically() {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;
    $product_id = 339; // product id
    $cart_total = 199.99;
    $in_cart = false;
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] === $product_id ) {
            $in_cart = true;
            $key = $cart_item_key;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( WC()->cart->total < $cart_total ) {
        if ( $in_cart ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $key );
    }
}
```